# Always use default as input to describe-symbol function

Tags: help, interactive

I want to map `describe-symbol` to shortcut, but I constantly have to press additional `enter` for show describe on found `default` suggestion. Is there a way to force emacs to newer ask for confirmation with enter on `describe-symbol` call?

P.S. Maybe there's a way to do this from elisp function call? I use that wrapper function to get symbol under cursor description, how shoult I tweak it to make it works as I wish?

```
(defun sandric/hydra-dash (arg)
  "Hydra help dash"
  (interactive "P")
  (call-interactively 'describe-symbol arg))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how to modify or even re-use the interactive spec, but making a new function is very easy:

```el
(defun describe-symbol-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (describe-symbol (or (symbol-at-point) (error "No symbol-at-point"))))
```

BTW, `describe-symbol` is on `C-h o` by default, alongside with `C-h f` (`describe-function`) and `C-h v` (`describe-variable`).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```el
(defun my-describe-symbol (symbol)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (let* ((v-or-f (symbol-at-point))
          (found  (if v-or-f (cl-some (lambda (x) (funcall (nth 1 x) v-or-f))
                                      describe-symbol-backends)))
          (v-or-f (if found v-or-f (function-called-at-point)))
          (found  (or found v-or-f))
          (enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
          (val    (if found
                      (format "%s" v-or-f)
                    (completing-read
                     "Describe symbol: " obarray
                     (lambda (vv) (cl-some (lambda (x) (funcall (nth 1 x) vv))
                                      describe-symbol-backends))
                     t nil nil (if found (symbol-name v-or-f))))))
     (list (if (equal val "") v-or-f (intern val)))))
  (describe-symbol symbol))
```

That just reproduces the `interactive` spec from `describe-symbol`, modifying it slightly to use the default value, when present.

Comment: Thanks, that works, although mb there's cleaner solution so I'll wait a little before marking as best answer.

Comment: FWIW, I would not have coded the `interactive` spec that way - it's not my style. I tried to keep it as close as possible to the original in `describe-symbol`, so you can easily see the change I made to it.